# sonarlint ruleset files when working with version control

Tags: file, tfs, code-analysis, rules, sonarlint

We are using TFS and the added .ruleset files now participates in the check-in process. However, does not make sense to check-in those files. Just ignore the file on the source control does not solve the problem because those files are added in the csproj structure as well. Is there a plan to keep those files in a folder outside the project structure? Why, when connected to the SonarQube server, the plugin just download those files at the analysis time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to keep .ruleset files outside the project structure, as the rule set is to meet specific project needs associated with code analysis. It sits in a project properties.